# Google App Engine: How to use RescoringMatchScorer for scoring documents

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I am trying to use Google App Engine's Search API to get documents based on keywords. My documents have two parts: a title and a description.

I have read the documentation of RescoringMatchScorer and it says that it can return a score based on weighted term frequency of different document parts. But I cannot figure out how to specify weights to the document parts. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Text Search API does that automatically based on number of word occurrences on the document. If you have let's say a document with words: ab ab it would have score 2 (i'm simplifying things), but if you have a document: ab it would have score 1.

Comment: I understand that. My question is that I want to give more weight to a particulat part of the document. For example document where "ab" occurs in title should have more weight than document where "ab" occurs in body.

Comment: @marrock Have you figured it?

Comment: @rajeshujade No, I ended up giving the same weight to title and description. Based on this [source code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/search/RescoringMatchScorer.java) it looks like they haven't added the support for it yet.